# Change Azure VM Disks from SSD to HDD

Tags: azure, hard-drive, hdd

I have an Azure VM with 8 disks attached, and all of these disks are formatted as one disk on the OS. They are all SSD's, but I would like to change them to HDD's. Can I just do this for each of them in the portal with impunity, or will this cause an error on the OS due to the fact they are all formatted as one? I just want to make sure I'm safe to do this without potentially corrupting a lot of data held across all of them. Thanks

Comment: What research you did? Because first link in my google search point me to MS document about exactly this case

Comment: I see that I can convert the disks if the VM is stopped, but just wanted to make sure that if the disks are all formatted as one disk on the VM OS it wouldn't cause a problem - I couldn't see any information on that part anywhere. I guess it should be fine though if MS states they can just be changed.